# How can I set a request timeout for a specific endpoint in Express.js?

Tags: node.js, express, http

*Express v4.17, Node v18*

### Problem:

I have an `/upload` endpoint where I want the client to be able to continue sending data for hours, in a single request.

However, Node's [`server.requestTimeout`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#serverrequesttimeout) defaults to 5 minutes and this will time-out any request running longer than that. This is not good enough for uploading large files. I don't want to increase the `requestTimeout` for the whole server.

Setting the timeout on the `req` object is not what I'm looking for:

- `req.setTimeout(ms)` is an alias for `req.socket.setTimeout(ms)`
- `req.socket.setTimeout(ms)` sets the SOCKET timeout

  > A socket timeout is the timeout when waiting for individual packets. It's a common misconception that a socket timeout is the timeout to receive the full response.
- `req.connection.setTimeout(ms)` sets the max time for a connection to be SET UP

  > A connection timeout is the maximum amount of time that the program is willing to wait to setup a connection to another process. You aren't getting or posting any application data at this point, just establishing the connection, itself.

### What I tried:

I tried setting the timeouts directly on the `req` object (and `res`, for some reason I saw this suggested)

Here's an example middleware function:

```js
const reqTimeoutSetter = (req, res, next) => {
    req.setTimeout(3600000); // one hour
    req.socket.setTimeout(3600000);
    req.connection.setTimeout(3600000);

    res.setTimeout(3600000);
    res.socket.setTimeout(3600000);
    res.connection.setTimeout(3600000);

    next();
};
```

and my endpoint & server setup:

```js
const app = express();

app.post('/', [reqTimeoutSetter, /* multer middleware */], (req, res) => {
    // ...
});

const server = http.createServer({
    requestTimeout: 10000 // 10 seconds
}, app);

server.listen(5000);
```

and the request still times out based on `server.requestTimeout`.

**Is there a way to set the timeout for receiving the entire request from the client, for a specific endpoint (not server-wide)?**

Comment: Can you just remove the server-wide timeout and re-add it after the upload routes?

Comment: @Evert No, that's not how it works. `requestTimeout` is just a public field of the server object, it's not applied to individual routes. 

If you look at the [http.Server source code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/db81af61ce0d55c052723e30ac7f6b7ad60f70c3/lib/_http_server.js#L599), it just uses `this.requestTimeout` in `checkConnections()`  to decide if to timeout a request.